# Ruby: How to find to similarity in two arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, uniq

I am trying to find the common elements in two arrays.

```
pairs = Array.new
a = exchange_one.get_symbols
b = exchange_two.get_symbols
c = a+b
c.uniq{|pair| pairs << pair}
```

I am combining the two arrays using **+**

Then I am calling **uniq** to remove the duplicate, but passing it to a block so the found duplicates can be added to an array before they are deleted.

For some reason the array pairs is just the entire **c** array.

What is the correct way to find array similarities.

Comment: What are the common elements in `[1,1,2]` and `[1,3,1]`? One `1` or two? if `1` it's just `arr1 & arr2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First understand what are you doing and what you want.

For eg.

```
a = 15.times.map { rand 6 }
  #=> [1, 0, 5, 3, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 2, 3]
b = 15.times.map { rand 6 }
  #=> [3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 5, 1, 4, 2, 0, 0, 4]
```

Now what are you doing

```
c = a + b 
  #=> [1, 0, 5, 3, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 5, 1, 4, 2, 0, 0, 4]
```

c - only combine arrays irrespective of content hence get all values.

Now

```
pairs = Array.new
c.uniq{|pair| pairs << pair}
```

Here **uniq** is just act as a iterator means if you check 'pair' then it iterate all the values of 'c' and insert those values in 'pairs' array.

check this

```
c.uniq{|pair| puts pair}
```

Thats why you are getting all values within 'pairs' array.

The best way to find similarity in arrays is `(a&b)`, but you can make changes in your code as follow to achieve it.

```
 pairs = (arr1+arr2).uniq

OR

 pairs = arr1 & arr2 #best and efficient way.
```

Comment: Note that adding the two arrays together and calling `uniq` is much less efficient than the intersection operator. But +1 for the breakdown of why OPs code didn’t work.

Answer (score 8):

If your goal is simply to determine which elements are the same between two arrays, you can use the intersection operator [`Array#&`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-26).

```
a = exchange_one.get_symbols
b = exchange_two.get_symbols

intersection = a & b
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose:

```
arr1 = 15.times.map { rand 6 }
  #=> [1, 0, 4, 0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 2, 4, 4, 1, 3, 1, 1] 
arr2 = 15.times.map { rand 6 }
  #=> [5, 5, 4, 1, 5, 1, 5, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0, 4, 5, 0]
```

`arr1` contains `5` `1`s and `arr2` contains `2` `1`s. If, by "common elements" you wish to report that both arrays contain `[5, 2].min #=> 2` `1`s, and similar counts for the other elements that appear in either array, you can do the following:

```
h1 = count(arr1)
  #=> {1=>5, 0=>3, 4=>3, 2=>2, 3=>2} 
h2 = count(arr2)
  #=> {5=>5, 4=>3, 1=>2, 0=>4, 2=>1} 
(h1.keys | h2.keys).each_with_object({}) { |k,h| h[k] = [h1[k], h2[k]].min }
  #=> {1=>2, 0=>3, 4=>3, 2=>1, 3=>0, 5=>0}

def count(arr)
  arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |n,h| h[n] += 1 }
end
```